# Programmatically reload Expo app with SDK 39?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Previously you could call `Updates.reload()`, but that's been removed.

A new method, `Updates.reloadAsync()` has been added, but doesn't function in development mode. Unfortunately our app relies on being able to restart itself. Is there some way to do this in SDK 39, or are we left to rewrite our application to accommodate this removal?

Comment: Have you asked this question in the Expo forums? If you have please share the link with me.

Comment: @Amr I did not, but I've added an answer to my question below.

Answer (score 1):

[The functionality was added back in a patch version of SDK 39.](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/10464#issuecomment-703178030)

**Make sure you have at minimum these package versions:**

```js
  "expo": "^39.0.3",
  "expo-updates": "~0.3.5",
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz",
```